# One's more about grails searchable plugin

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I have two simple domains:

```
public class Hotel {
 static searchable = true
 Source source
 City city
 HotelType type
 long sourceid
 float lat
 float lon
 static hasMany = [hotelTexts:HotelText]
 static mapping = {
  hotelTexts batchSize:10
  }
}

public class HotelText {
    static searchable = true
    static belongsTo = [hotel:Hotel]
    String lang
    String name
    String description
    String address
    static mapping = {
        batchSize:10
        description type:"text"
    }
}
```

I'm totally new in searchable plugin but i believe that it could help me with my problem.
So, the task is to find Hotels by city and then **sort result by name**. Without sorting it could be easily done with dynamic finders help but...

**Summary:**

1. Find hotels by city.
2. Sort result by hotel name(for given language).
3. Support pagination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

public class Hotel {

```
static searchable = {
     hotelTexts component: true
}

...
```

}

public class HotelText {
    static searchable = {
         name boost: 2.0
    }

```
...
```

}